# Arabic Dataset Cleaning: Removing everything but Arabic text

Tags: data-cleaning

I have a huge dataset in the Arabic language, I cleaned the data from special characters, English characters. But, I discovered that the dataset contains many other languages like Chinese, Japanese, Russian, etc. The problem is that I can't tell exactly what other languages are there mixed with the Arabic language, so I need a solution to remove everything in the text rather than Arabic characters from a pandas data frame.
here is my code:

```
def clean_txt(input_str):
    try:
        if input_str: # if the input string is not empty do the following
              
            input_str = re.sub('[?؟!@#$%&*+~\/=><]+^' , '' , input_str) # Remove some of special chars 
            input_str=re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z?]', '', input_str).strip() # remove english chars 
            input_str = re.sub('[\\s]+'," ",input_str) # Remove all spaces
            input_str = input_str.replace("_" , ' ') #Remove underscore
            input_str = input_str.replace("ـ" , '') # Remove Arabic tatwelah
            input_str =input_str.replace('"','')# Remove "
            input_str =input_str.replace("''",'')# Remove ''
            input_str =input_str.replace("'",'')# Remove '
            input_str =input_str.replace(".",'')# Remove .
            input_str =input_str.replace(",",'')# Remove ,
            input_str =input_str.replace(":",' ')# Remove :
            input_str=re.sub(r" ?\([^)]+\)", "", str(input_str))  #Remove text between ()
            input_str = input_str.strip() # Trim input string

    except:
        return input_str
    return input_str
```

[image: Sample-data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer:

```
text ='大谷育江 صباح الخيرfff :"""%#$@&!~(2009 مرحباً Добро пожаловать fffff أحمــــد ݓ'


t = re.sub(r'[^0-9\u0600-\u06ff\u0750-\u077f\ufb50-\ufbc1\ufbd3-\ufd3f\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufe70-\ufefc\uFDF0-\uFDFD]+', ' ', text)
t
' صباح الخير 2009 مرحباً أحمــــد ݓ'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_str = re.sub(r'[^ \\p{Arabic}]', '', input_str)
```

All those not-space and not-Arabic are removed. You might add interpunction, would need to take care of empties, like `()` but you could look into Unicode script/category names.

---

***Corrected*** Instead of `InArabic` it should be `Arabic`, see [Unicode scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unicode)).

Comment: Hello, thanks for posting your solution. but I tried it with the Japanese language and it gave error: input_str ='大谷育江'
input_str = re.sub(r'[^ \p{InArabic}]', '', input_str)
print(input_str)    error: bad escape \p at position 3

Comment: Then maybe `\p` should be written as `\\p` inside the string as in java. Otherwise the language does not implement Unicode names. Corrected the answer.

Comment: Since this is about "alphabet" rather than "language", I don't see how it's relevant to the OP's question. The input corpus includes numerous unspecified languages. Presumably some of them include Baluchi, Brahui, Central, Dari, Garshuni, Kashmiri, Kazakh, Kurdish, Pashto, Persian, Punjabi, Saraiki, Sindhi, Somali, Urdu, Uyghur, Uzbek. Each of those employs an Arabic writing system, yet we wouldn't equate any of them with Arabic language.

Comment: @J_H I looked it up just now - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unicode) - and it should have been `\\p{Arabic}.

Comment: even though \\p{Arabic}. removes everything, I posted the answer

Comment: @Mai Congrates, _that_ was some work! It would be interesting to see how `\p{Arabic}` was implemented to see differences. Accept your answer, By the way I do not need points.

Answer (score -1):

Language detection is a solved problem.

Simplest algorithmic approach is to scan a bunch of single-language texts for character bi-grams,
and compute distance between those and the bi-gram frequency of target text.

Simplest thing for *you* to implement is to call into this NLTK routine:

```
from nltk.classify.textcat import TextCat

nltk.download(['crubadan', 'punkt'])
tc = TextCat()

>>> tc.guess_language('Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party.')
'eng'
>>> tc.guess_language('Il est maintenant temps pour tous les hommes de bien de venir en aide à leur parti.')
'fra'
>>> tc.guess_language('لقد حان الوقت الآن لجميع الرجال الطيبين لمساعدة حزبهم.')
'arb'
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution, but my problem is not language detection. referring to the above code if we modify the text in the Arabic language with Japanese like this: tc.guess_language(' 大谷育江 لقد حان الوقت الآن لجميع الرجال الطيبين لمساعدة حزبهم.') the outpt is arb

Comment: Oh sure, I understood that. Your comment is all about "what is a document?" Is it a word? A span of words? A span for which each word belongs to same language? Given the .guess_language() functional primitive, now it is your task to carve up a bigger corpus into small "documents" for which the function returns sensible results. The primitive works better when you give it at least half a dozen words, at least thirty or forty characters. You might want to run a K-word windowing function over your corpus, and use that to narrow down where the language transitions occur.